# Что запускает php скрипты?

Tags: php

Какая программа запускает php скрипты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ПХП скрипты запускает php. Так называется интерпретатор, а апач только передаёт ему файлы. Может я и ошибаюсь, но на линукс сервере наличие только апача позволяет запускать только html страницы. 
Если честно, то это очень странный вопрос ИМХО, хоть иногда гугл юзайте

Comment: apache может исполнять cgi, а ими может быть хоть bash скрипт, хоть на асме код написанный, главное что бы параметры принимал правильно и в консоль html выводил.

Comment: <s>html</s> хоть что-нибудь)

Answer (score 2):

PHP скрипт запускает веб-сервер (например, Апач) или пользователь, а исполняет PHP интерпретатор.

1. `curl http://localhost/phpinfo.php` - через сервер
2. `php /var/www/html/phpinfo.php` - вручную

Соответственно, надо либо установить сервер + PHP, либо просто PHP.

Answer (score 0):

apache+php(в готовом виде - http://www.denwer.ru/)

Comment: программа так  и называется?

Comment: не программа, а веб сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Как ни странно, но php скрипты выполняет php.

Интерпретатор можно скачать на официальном сайте http://www.php.net/

Насколько я помню запускается так:

```
php <путь до файла .php>
```

Answer (score -1):

Apache + php, желательно брать php не последней версии. Мой Вам совет, не нужно, могут вылазить некоторые непредвиденные ошибки, а если вы ещё и новичок в данном деле, то это сугубо скажется на Вас.

Можете попробывать скачать Zend Server. Похожий на Denwer, + консоль сделана. Для проектов на Zend фреймворке.

Answer (score -1):

Apache+php готовый к установке: [Денвер](http://denwer.ru) , либо [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/ru/xampp.html)